# Error creating Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm getting an error while creating a project with `laravel new project` command.
The project is created, but it outputs an error while doing so. After it end crafting the project, you can't run it using `php artisan serve`.

The log it outputs while crafting the application is:

```
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 70 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v2.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing erusev/parsedown (1.7.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.5.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v4.1.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v4.1.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/routing (v4.1.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/process (v4.1.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v4.1.3): Downloading (100%)
    Failed to download symfony/http-foundation from dist: The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems): ZipArchive::extractTo(C:\Users\manager\Desktop\project/vendor/composer/08eb24bd/symfony-http-foundation-7d93e35\Tests\File\Fixtures\directory/.empty): failed to open stream: Permission denied
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v4.1.3): Cloning 7d93e35476 from cache


  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.

  - https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation.git
    fatal: destination path 'C:\Users\manager\Desktop\project\vendor\symfony\http-foundation' already exists and is not an empty directory.

  - git@github.com:symfony/http-foundation.git
    fatal: destination path 'C:\Users\manager\Desktop\project\vendor\symfony\http-foundation' already exists and is not an empty directory.


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...

Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

The log it outputs when you try to run the application is:

```
PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\manager\Desktop\project/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\manager\Desktop\project\artisan on line 18

Warning: require(C:\Users\manager\Desktop\project/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\manager\Desktop\project\artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\manager\Desktop\project/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\manager\Desktop\project\artisan on line 18

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\manager\Desktop\project/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\manager\Desktop\project\artisan on line 18
```

I tried to clone the `https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation.git` repo and it works just fine using `git clone https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation.git` on the same terminal.

I also tried to look for the error on the internet, but nothing helped me so far. I want to solve it for all future projects, not for this project in particularly.

Comment: remove the vendor directory and then try `composer install`

Comment: @Quezler You mean the vendor folder from the project I created or another vendor folder?

Comment: the one in the project folder (`C:\Users\manager\Desktop\project\vendor`)

Comment: @Quezler But that implies on me doing this every single time I create a new project, right? I was looking for a more "definitive solution" :\

Comment: from what i can see this is a single time issue, a symfony package already existed in the vendor folder somehow, so please try the above and let me know if that fails or succeeds

Comment: @Quezler I tried and it failed again with a similar error. A log can be found here: https://codeshare.io/G7DDmD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177301/discussion-between-leonardosibela-and-quezler).

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan config:cache
composer update
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.